# Switch-Case on Class.PropertyName (not value)

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have a class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` like this:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string _color;
    public string Color
    {
        get{ return _color; }
        set
        {
            _color = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    ...        

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

When the `Color` property setter is called, it calls `RaisePropertyChanged()` which automatically gets the property name i.e `"Color"` and uses that to populate `PropertyChangedEventArgs`. Instead of you manually typing in the property name.

This is good because it prevents possible bugs in your code since you dont have to manually type the property name. Also helps when refactoring your code since you aren't hard-coding any strings.

**My Question**
I have an event handler for `PropertyChanged`. How can I use a switch-case construct without hard-coding the Property Names as strings. So something like this:

```
void Person_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e){
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case PropertyNameOf(Person.Color);
            //some stuff
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Is this possible? I want to do this so I can keep the benefits I mentioned above.

Comment: What do you need to do inside of the `case`?

Comment: @NateBarbettini Some stuff. I left it out because I don't think it was relevant to the question

Comment: You're  looking for C# 6's `nameof` operator.

Comment: @Krimson I was thinking that you could use reflection to look up the available properties of the object and compare... but I wasn't thinking all the way through your example. `nameof` does seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @SLaks That is true, unfortunately I am using .net4.5

Comment: @Krimson: C# 6 can compile to any version of .Net after 2.0.  You can use VS2015 and continue to target .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Expression<Func<T>>` to do what you want.

Define this method:

```
private string ToPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> @this)
{
    var @return = string.Empty;
    if (@this != null)
    {
        var memberExpression = @this.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression != null)
        {
            @return = memberExpression.Member.Name;
        }
    }
    return @return;
}
```

Then you can write this:

```
void Person_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e){
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case ToPropertyName(() => Person.Color);
            //some stuff
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Now you have some strongly-typed joy. :-)

---

To get switch-like functionality without `switch` and messy `if`/`then`/`else` you can do this:

```
void Person_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var @switch = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
    {
        { ToPropertyName(() => Person.Color), () => { /* some stuff */ } },
        { ToPropertyName(() => Person.Size), () => { /* some other stuff */ } },
        { ToPropertyName(() => Person.Shape), () => { /* some more stuff */ } },
    };

    if (@switch.ContainsKey(e.PropertyName))
    {
        @switch[e.PropertyName]();
    }
    else
    {
        /* default stuff */
    }
}
```

Comment: One question. How are you able to do `Person.Color` since `Color` is a non static field?

Comment: @Krimson - This code is written to work with non-static fields/properties.

Comment: I tried using your code. But I get an error at: `case ToPropertyName(() => Person.Color);`. Which is `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TestingArea.Person.Color.get`

Comment: @Krimson - is `Person` a class or an object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Person is a class which I use to create an object `Person mySelf = new Person();`

Comment: @Krimson - Then `Person` is the class and `mySelf` is the object. If your `Color` property is `static` then the above code works, but if not then you need to put `case ToPropertyName(() => mySelf.Color);` or `case ToPropertyName(() => this.Color);` if the method is in the class itself.

Comment: @Enigmativity The function works as expected however, I don't think its possible to use it in a switch-case since each case requires a constant value. Either way that problem is out of scope from my original question. Ill stick to an if-else statement instead. Thanks though :)

Comment: @Krimson - Good call re `switch`. I try to avoid `switch` so I've added an alternative.

Answer (score 6):

In C# 6.0, you can use the [nameof()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) keyword.

The keyword is replaced by string literals at compile time. So it's much better than using lambda expression with code that digs the name of your symbol at runtime on a performance point of view, and it also works with `switch()` statements:

```
switch(e.PropertyName)
{
    case nameof(Foo.Bar):
        break;
}
```

You will also get a compile time error if you change the name of the property in the class, but forget to change it in your switch statement. So this approach is much less bugprone.