# WPF Material Design Binding Kind of PackIcon doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I try to change the Kind of a Packicon programmatically.

That's my code now:

I implemented the Interface INotifyPropertyChagned now:

```
public partial class OwnExtendedMessageBox : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Then I added these lines

```
    //property of Binding changed
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
```

Then I call it like that

```
        switch (MessageBoxIcon)
        {
            case OwnMessageBoxIcon.None:
                MessageBoxIconKind = PackIconKind.Box;
                break;
            case OwnMessageBoxIcon.Info:
                MessageBoxIconKind = PackIconKind.Information;
                break;
            case OwnMessageBoxIcon.Warning:
                MessageBoxIconKind = PackIconKind.Warning;
                break;
            case OwnMessageBoxIcon.Error:
                MessageBoxIconKind = PackIconKind.Error;
                break;
            default:
                MessageBoxIconKind = PackIconKind.Box;
                break;
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("MessageBoxIconKind");
```

WPF:

```
<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding MessageBoxIconKind}" Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush}" ...
```

I also tryed it with a string, but it also doesn't worke

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553967/switch-case-on-class-propertyname-not-value) should help you

Comment: Make sure that `MessageBoxIconKind` is a public property of the OwnExtendedMessageBox class, and that the DataContext of the Window is set to itself, e.g. by `DataContext = this;` in its constructor. Otherwise, change the Binding to `Kind="{Binding MessageBoxIconKind, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"`

Comment: @Clemens: I tried this. I added DataContext = this; to the constructor. I also tried to change the Binding. Nothing worked.
Does it matter, that this window is opended with ShowDialog? 

For explenation: This is an Own MessageBox window.
When creating the window, the parameters are set after InitializeComponent();

Maybe it is better to use a Name for the PackIcon to access it directly and no binding?

Comment: I gave the PackIcon a Name now and access it directly with WindowIcon.Kind = PackIconKind.Info. This works. But shouldn't it also work somehow with binding?

Comment: In this case it is no problem to give it a x:Name and change the Icon using this.

Comment: What if you set the `MessageBoxIconKind` property before InitializeComponent?